# encoded public key of x509 Certificate from java and dart are different

Tags: java, dart, x509certificate, public-key, pem

I have get public key from x509 certificate using basic_utils package in flutter but it is different from java encoded public key.

Java code

```
  public static byte[] getPublicKeyFromCert(String certificateValue) {
    byte[] CertData = Base64.decode(certificateValue, Base64.DEFAULT);
    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(CertData);
    CertificateFactory certificatefactory = null;
    try {
        certificatefactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    X509Certificate objcert509 = null;
    try {
        objcert509 = (X509Certificate)certificatefactory.generateCertificate(byteArrayInputStream);
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] publicKey = objcert509.getPublicKey().getEncoded();
    return publicKey;
}
```

output : [48, 86, 48, 16, 6, 7, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1, 6, 5, 43, -127, 4, 0, 10, 3, 66, 0, 4, -2, 6, 1, -3, -114, 15, -55, -25, -65, 101, -90, 85, 7, 18, -43, -117, -13, -124, 67, 29, -15, -70, 114, 37, 56, 75, 112, -41, -102, -18, -39, -26, -121, -100, 127, -25, 30, 37, 84, -112, 88, 73, -56, -97, -85, 7, -94, -27, -113, 38, 39, 40, 75, 76, 82, 106, 7, -68, 83, -127, -103, -52, 125, 89]

Dart Code

```
 var base64Str = base64.decode(certificateValue);
var x509Certificate = x509UtilsLocal.crlDerToPem(base64Str);
X509CertificateData x509certificateData = X509Utils.x509CertificateFromPem(x509Certificate);
print("getPublicKeyFromCert" + hex.decode(x509certificateData.publicKeyData.bytes).toString());
var bytes = hex.decode(x509certificateData.publicKeyData.bytes);
```

output : [0, 4, 254, 6, 1, 253, 142, 15, 201, 231, 191, 101, 166, 85, 7, 18, 213, 139, 243, 132, 67, 29, 241, 186, 114, 37, 56, 75, 112, 215, 154, 238, 217, 230, 135, 156, 127, 231, 30, 37, 84, 144, 88, 73, 200, 159, 171, 7, 162, 229, 143, 38, 39, 40, 75, 76, 82, 106, 7, 188, 83, 129, 153, 204, 125, 89]

Comment: Part of the issue is your are using different data types. The bytes in Dart is clearly unsigned (since the values goes between 0 and 255) while the values in Java are signed (goes from -128 to 127). But this does not explain the start of the certificate being different.

Comment: I don't dart, but the value you show is _only_ the (per-algorithm) value from the BIT STRING part of SubjectPublicKeyInfo, while Java returns the encoding of the whole SubjectPublicKeyInfo SEQUENCE; see rfc5280 4.1. In particular this is a key for X9-type-EC (OID 1.2.840.10045.2.1) on curve secp256k1 (OID 1.3.132.0.10) so its BIT STRING value is, after a prefix byte 00 for unused_bits in DER, the point format defined in SEC1 and referenced in rfc5480 2.2, in this case uncompressed (first byte 04 followed by 32 bytes X and 32 bytes Y).